# LTSpice predefined components for ideal Voltage Gain and Sum

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to enter a circuit found in a Book from C.P.Basso which contains:

- ideal gain stage with one input and one output (Vout=Vin*k)
- ideal adder stage, which has two inputs and one output (Vout=VinA+VinB)

I could reproduce these by using ideal OpAmps, but aren't there already such predefined components in the LTSpice library ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort by the OP.

Comment: You are looking for a `voltage dependant voltage source` **E** component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal voltage gain is implemented with a VCVS (voltage-controlled voltage source). You specify the two terminals of the controlling (input) voltage and a single gain parameter.

You can combine two voltage sources just by putting them in series. If that's not the configuration you need, use two VCVS that are controlled by the two input voltages, each with a gain of 1.0. Then place the two VCVS in series.

This is a pretty standard technique for any SPICE simulation.

Comment: Components `e` for a VCVS which provides Vout = k*Vin and `bv` for a behavioural voltage source which can be a function, e.g. Vin1 + Vin2